# C: Include a file which includes a file that also needs to be included in the main program

Tags: c, header, include

I have a header file (`generalfunctions.h`):

```
#ifndef GENERALFUNCTIONS_H
#define GENERALFUNCTIONS_H

//functionsdeclartion for example
int getInt(char* text);

#endif /* GENERALFUNCTIONS_H */
```

and a C file `generalfunctions.c` where I include this headerfile (so I can use some of the functions within each other and don't have bother with their order) and code out the functions.

`generalfunctions.c`:

```
#include "generalfunctions.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 //functions implentaion for example
 int getInt(char* text){
    int  i;
    printf("%s\n", text);
    if(scanf("%d", &i)==EOF){
        printf("INT_ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
    return i;
}
//...
```

Now I need some of these functions in a file called `project_objects.c` that together with `project_objects.h` defines a couple of structs, unions, variables and functions with these things I need for my project.

`project_objects.h`:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

typedef struct  point{
    int x;
    int y;
} point;

point create_point(void);
void print_point(point *p);
//...

#endif /* POINT_H */
```

`project_objects.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "project_objects.h"
#include "generalfunctions.h"

point create_point(void){
  point p;
  p.x=getInt("Give my a x");
  p.y=getInt("Give my a y");
   return p;
}
void print_point(point *p){
      printf("x: %d\n", p->x);
      printf("y: %d\n", p->y);
}
//..
```

However I also need some of the functions described in `generalfunctions.h` directly in my main program:

```
#include "generalfunctions.c"
#include "project_objects.c"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int i=getInt("How many points would you like to create?");
  while(i<1){
      i=getInt("Cannot create a negative number of points. How many points would you like to create?");
  }
  point pointarray[i];
  for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
      pointarray[j]=create_point();
  }
  for(int k=0; k<i; k++){
       printf("Point %d:\n", k+1);
       print_point(pointarray+k);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This seems to work. If I just include the h-files than I get the error that `getInt()` isn't defined when I link. And before when I included the C file for general functions in `project_object.c` I got errors for duplication. But now the files seem more dependent on each other than I planned. I also don't understand why this works.

Comment: Do you *define* functions in the *.h* files?

Comment: No I just declare them there.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ans show us, and also show the exact errors you get (by copy-paste).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I just did. It works, but looks quiet ugly.

Comment: Learn how to handle separate compilation of object files and how to create libraries, and then use them.  The file `general_functions.c` should be in a library — programs that need any of those general functions include the header and link against the library.  This is the way the standard C library works; the headers such as `<stdio.h>` declare the functions and are used by your code to gain access to the functions, but the program is linked against the standard C library. The difference is that the C compiler links the standard C library by default but not your custom library (by default).

Comment: You might find it beneficial to have separate source files for each function, or each small family of functions, within your library of general functions.  However, that's for a later date.

Comment: Ok I compile these c files to o-files, include the h-files and somehow feed them into the complier with a -l option if I have read this right, to you have a link to a easy to understand tutorium?

Answer (score 2):

Do not include *.c*-files. Write function protytypes in *.h*-files and include them.

project_object.h

```
typedef int faa;
```

foo.h

```
include "project_object.h"

faa foo( faa x ); // prototype for function "foo"
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"

faa foo( faa x ) // implementation of function "foo"
{
    return x + 666;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "project_object.h"
#include "foo.h" // include .h-file with prototype of function "foo"

int main( void )
{
   faa x;
   x = foo(0);   // call function "foo"

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I  think you need to write something like x=foo(0); or so but beside that have you read my question? I have the file project_object with in a typedef faa. Now I in a function dealing with faa I need foo, but I also need foo dircetly in my main-programm how to I do it? Can I write #include "foo.h" both with in the main-file and the faa-file if I have a #include "faa.h" in the main? If not why and how to do it?

Comment: And I edit the question, but I still needed to include the c file.

Comment: @user3284214: You need to link your with the object file created by compiling `generalfunctions.c` into `generalfunctions.o` (or `generalfunctions.obj` on Windows), and you need to link with the object file created by compiling `project_objects.c` into `project_objects.o`, as well as the object file created by compiling `main.c` into `main.o`.  Or you need to put `generalfunctions.o` and `project_objects.o` into a library and link with that library.  You do not want to include the `.c` files into `main.c` — especially when the libraries get bigger.